# How to zoom a UIScrollView inside of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to add a `UIScrollView` inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`. The idea is that you can use pinch to zoom the `UIScrollView` (and with it, the image within), but the scrollview doesn't seem to handle any gesture. I'm guessing they are being caught by the `UICollectionView`.

I've set the delegate of the `UIScrollView` to be the `UICollectionViewCell`, but none of the delegate methods are being called.

EDIT:
I've made a github repo with the code (simplified as much as I could). Even though it's just a few lines of code, I cannot see what I did wrong.

EDIT2: After the answer was found, I added the fixes to the above-mentioned repo, hope others find it helpful too :)

https://github.com/krummler/gallery-pinchzoom-example

Comment: Thanks for putting the updated code into a repo. It was useful to me!

Comment: link broken. please update the link

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might want to try manipulating the UIGestureRecognizers in order to do that. In the `GalleryViewController`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    GalleryImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"galleryImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ImageContext *imageContext = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageContext = imageContext;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:cell.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:cell.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];

    return cell;
}
```

From [Apple's documentation on UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_62):

> Attaching a gesture recognizer to a view defines the scope of the represented gesture, causing it to receive touches hit-tested to that view and all of its subviews. The view retains the gesture recognizer.

So you'll also want to make sure to remove them when the cell is not showing anymore.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
  didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell 
    forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get the cell instance and ...
    [self.collectionView removeGestureRecognizer:cell.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer];
    [self.collectionView removeGestureRecognizer:cell.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Since you're not modifying the UIGestureRecognizer's delegate, only its scope, it will still control the zooming of just that cell's scrollview.

**EDIT**:

I added the `panGestureRecognizer` to the above examples, following a suggestion from the OP that it was needed. The zooming itself is completely handled by the `pinchGestureRecognizer`, but it's true that in most cases, after zooming an image to a point where only a subset of it is visible, you'll want to pan to move the visible portion around. That is, it's part of a proper zooming experience.

Comment: Awesome! I had to do the same thing for the `panGestureRecognizer` and I was good to go! Thanks :) (cant award the bounty yet for some reason, I'll do it later.)

Comment: @matehat Im using swift, and my didEndDisplaying cell, I keep getting a 'found nil unwrapping optional' error.  I've tried making it 'if let', it never gets called. :/    Here is how i'm getting the instance : let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FSImageCell

Comment: i didn't need to add / remove the gesturerecognizers to the cell. Both pinching and panning were already working for me in the cell while still allowing me to scroll horizontally through my collectionview. I was using fullscreen cells for an image gallery.

Answer (score 26):

I just made an implementation for **SWIFT 3** on **iOS 9.3+** and all i done was:

**1. Place the image view inside a scrollview**

[image: storyboard example]

**2. Connect the scrollview delegate to collectionview cell class**

**3. Implement the code below on the collectionview subclass**

```
class FullScreenImageTextDetailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet var scrollview: UIScrollView!
     @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

     override func awakeFromNib() {
         self.scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
         self.scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 3.5
         self.scrollview.delegate = self
     }

     func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
         return self.backgroundImageView
     }
}
```

No gesture recognizer adding or removing on the parent collectionview controller was necessary, worked like a charm!

Thanks for previous examples for reaching this!

Comment: Great answer. Putting the viewForZooming delegate callback in the cell class is key.

Comment: Can you provide .swift and .xib files for this. This seems to be very simple, but i am not able to make it work at my end.

Answer (score 4):

Please add scrollview in your cell and your current cell image view add in scrollview.
then use below code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageContext *context = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    cell.cellScrollView.multipleTouchEnabled =YES;
    cell.cellScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    cell.cellScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    cell.cellScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.cellScrollView.delegate = self;
    cell.cellScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:context.thumbImageUrl]];

return cell;
}
 -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {   NSLog(@"%i",scrollView.subviews.count);
  for (UIView *v in scrollView.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        return v;
      }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check if all related view's multitouch is on. iOS disabled multitouch by default on most views to save energy.

Comment: I tried that, and tried to mimic some examples I could find, still I can't get it to work. I added a github repo url to the original post

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{            
  if (touch.view == [self myScrollView]) //<- whatever your scrollView is called 
    {
      return YES;
    }
  return NO;
}
```

Don't know your code but try playing around with the above code to see if you can filter your touches to the objects you want. The above code is from the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate).

Comment: Thanks, I added it in the collectionviewcell, it doesn't seem to be called for the scrollview in it, only for the outer view.

Answer (score 0):

The delegates are not getting called because you added it inside the UICollectionview.The touch events are availabel for the collection view which is the superview and hence not obtainable by the view inside.You may have to think of some other way to achieve this model.

`UICollectionView` is having the same pattern as `UITableView`,The problem occours in tableview inside scrollview ,that the touch event is accepted by scrollview[**which is the superview**] and to make the tableview scrollable in that case ,The scroll of scrollview must be disabled.This is another version of that problem

The apple docs says that the above said case make unpredictable results.So This may be same for your problem.

In my opinion  you ***must*** go for better design which can achieve what you look for

Answer (score 0):

```
I've set the delegate of the UIScrollView to be the UICollectionViewCell, but none of the delegate methods are being called.
```

For that just define one function in collectionViewCell

```
  @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView:UIScrollView!
  func setup(){
        mainScrollView.minimumZoomScale=1
        mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale=10.0

        mainScrollView.delegate=self

    }

   func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return yourimageviewinside of scrollview
    }
```

call this fuction in 
`collectionview(_,cellForItem )` method of collectionview