# UIScrollView contained inside of UICollectionViewCell not passing touch event to the CollectionView cell

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIScrollView inside a UICollectionViewCell so I can zoom an image within that ScrollView.
When I click the image I would like the CollectionViewCell to receive the event and pass it to the UICollectionView delegate.

I tried adding the following UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the container of the UIScrollView:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:ShouldReceiveTouch:
```

According to the answer I read the touch event should be passed on to the parent view - in this case the CollectionViewCell, but it isn't happening.

What should I do?

**Edit**
Please note that I'm not trying to pinch zoom inside the cell but rather be able to receive the touch events of the cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zoom a UIScrollView inside of a UICollectionViewCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960556/how-to-zoom-a-uiscrollview-inside-of-a-uicollectionviewcell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a good question as I was having the same problem. The only way I could get the uicollectionviewcell to respond to touches (intercepted from the uiscrollview) was to set

```
userinteractionenabled = NO
```

on the scrollview.

Comment: If you disable the interaction on scrollview, how are you going to zoom on the image inside?

Comment: @Puneet, you are correct that the zoom will not work. In my case it wasn't relevant since I wanted `collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to be called.

Comment: How is this the correct answer if you loose the zoom?