# UIScrollView in UICollectionViewCell with Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, pinchzoom, sdwebimage

I'm new in IOS. I try to create view images app that show fullscreen size images can zoom and when user zoom out images smaller than fullscreen size, image return fullscreen size and my idea is use UICollectionView set paging Enable , scrollDirection Horizontal. So my FlowLayout will be like this

```
var screenSize: CGRect!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal

    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
```

my CollectionViewCell identifier name "Cell" I drag ScrollView in it and drag image in that ScrollView

I outlet that two item in my CollectionViewCell Class like this

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var scrollCell: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgTest: UIImageView! 

}
```

next step in CollectionViewController set my dummy image something like this

```
var imageName:[String] = ["audi.png", "benz.png", "flok.png", "audi.png", "benz.png", "flok.png", "audi.png", "benz.png", "flok.png"]
```

and go to cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell.frame.size.width = screenSize.width
    cell.frame.size.height = screenSize.height
    // set cell size become fullscreen

    cell.imgTest.image = UIImage(named: imageName[indexPath.row])
    cell.imgTest.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size:cell.imgTest.image!.size)

    //call my dummy image to cell

    cell.scrollCell.addSubview(cell.imgTest)
    cell.scrollCell.contentSize = cell.imgTest.image!.size

    let scaleHeight = cell.scrollCell.frame.size.height / cell.scrollCell.contentSize.height
    let scaleWidth = cell.scrollCell.frame.size.width / cell.scrollCell.contentSize.width
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
    cell.scrollCell.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    cell.scrollCell.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    cell.scrollCell.zoomScale = minScale

    var doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scrollviewDoubleTapped")
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.scrollCell.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
```

I run this project and the problem is

1. scroll size don't equal my image size but over
2. my image can't zoom (I already check "user interaction enabled")
3. I try using pinch gesture to solve it but I don't know how to set minimumzoomscale to it and the images can't scroll when zoom in
4. By this code I try using image from json with SDWebImage I change code in cellForItemAtIndexPath from call dummy image to this

   cell.imgTest.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: dataArray[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loading.png"))

but this way Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

5. Where I go from here can anyone guide me in swift please

Comment: Have u found the solution?I am also stuck there...:(

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960556/how-to-zoom-a-uiscrollview-inside-of-a-uicollectionviewcell/41289418#41289418 for cell zooming

Answer (score 0):

instead of a collection view use a scrollview, much easier, and more flexible.  Check out this link very good tutorial.. You can merge the scrolled page and scroll zoom. [UIScrollView Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift)